# TinyMCE is broken

Tags: tinymce

After switching hosting server, the tinyMCE in the post editing screen does not fire up. Here is the message of the console.

[image: chrome console printout] As you can see, wp-tinymce.php seems to fail.

So far, I've tried :

- chmoding 777 (just to be sure) all the js/tinymce content
- reuploading the entire wp-include, forcing file replacement changing
- the header from javascript to json (here are the 3 tries i did):

try1:

```
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript; charset=UTF-8');
```

try2:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

try3:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

In Firefox 's firebug extension, the message is "illegal character"
and when i open the file from within firebug, instead of seeing the code, all chars are messed up. But in my IDE, the php code looks correct.

Any other idea? Would it be a server misconfiguration?

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: yes, same with firefox. But the firebug console message helps a little bit more. Apparently, it says "illegal characters" and when i open the file in firebug, instead of seeing the code, all chars are messed up. Adding this to the question.

Comment: did you tried reinstall wordpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding this to wp-config.php, which kills the js combining.

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
```

Comment: I nearly suggested doing just that, but thought to myself **"nah that won't help"**... note to self: suggest it anyway, you never know.. Thanks for posting to let us know you found a solution..

Comment: It would be interesting to know why the script concatenation fails from one day to the next.